# Mock Locations on Android 12

Tags: android, location, geofence

I am testing an app that uses geofencing and I need to be able to specify mock locations.  In my research I found old posts (5 years) talking about using Allow Mock Locations in developer options but that seems to only be in older versions of Android.  Now I see a place to specify a mock location app but no way to specify one.  I looked at code samples to create a mock location app but the permission that has to be set (ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION) appears to be only valid for system apps.  Is there no way to do this anymore without rooting?

Comment: Is the question how to test your app with a mock location provider, or how to create one? ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION is not reserved for system apps for what it's worth.

Comment: I have to create one that I can use to test my app.  If the permission is now restricted to system apps I don't see how anyone can create one that doesn't require root.  Unless I am missing something.  I know you guys know more tha I do so maybe you can show me what I am missing.

Comment: It does not require being a system app. There are also many mock location apps on the play store if you are simply wanting to test.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the apps that acquire `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` appear in developer options, which means you will be able to select your app as a `mock location app` when you add-in manifest

Secondly, `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` is not a system app permission. So there is no need for rooting the device or marking your app as a system app etc.